# A Region Where the Equation has a Unique Solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If we have the differential equation $dy/dx=y^{4/5}$ what is a region in the xy-plane where the equation has a unique solution.

I thought it would be the entire $xy$-plane because the function $y^{4/5}$ is defined for the entire $xy$-plane.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you get from $ 1=y(x)^{-4/5} y'(x) = 5(y(x)^{1/5})'$ ?

Answer (score 0):

y=$\frac{(x+C)^5}{3125}$

C being a constant

It's likely that the "unique solution" I'm guessing your teacher/professor was speaking of is when x=-C.  At that point, the graph is completely horizontal, y=0, $\frac{dy}{dx}$=0, $\frac{d²y}{dx²}$=0, $\frac{d^3y}{dx^3}$=0, etc.  You might want to get a second opinion on this though, just in case.  I really don't see anything that stands out about that graph except at that point and maybe at the asymptotes where y=$±\frac{∞^5}{3125}$

Answer (score 0):

The initial value problem with $y(0)=0$ has an infinity of solutions
$$
y(x)=\frac{\max(0,\,x-C)^5}{3125}
$$
with $C>0$. Similar branching can be achieved on the negative half axis.

This means that there is no uniqueness for this initial value. This you might also detect when trying to bound $f'(y)$.